# Clickonce Deployment after add a report with visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, clickonce, reportviewer, publish

I have a c# application that publishes to a server using click-once, so our company clients can run it. I upgrade my visual studio from 2010 to 2012. every thing is great so far and clients can run the application normally after my publishes.
then I add a report viewer Item to my application and it runs on my pc well. but after publishing the clients face this error:
unable to install or run the application. the application requires that assembly microsoft.reportviewer.ProcessingObjectModel version 11.0.0.0 to be installed in your GAC.

what should I do now, I search a lot but cant find a solution. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the report viewer as a prerequisite. Here is a link to MSDN that describes what is needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx

Comment: That link says I also need to include SQL Server CLR Types, and it doesn't even show up as an option in the prerequisites.